# Apache2/httpd not logging ip address

Tags: apache, apache2, rhel

Apache 2 logging client ip address as -. It seems like the header does not carry the client ip address. how to change this?

Comment: Add to the question the configuration of your log file in Apache.  Other point, do you have network devices (proxy, fw, ...) between the network and your Apache server?  They might need to add the X-Forwarded-For header to get the information all the way to your Apache server.

Comment: I figured it out, it was the %h that was needed instead of %i